# How to use teacher forcing in training model using LSTM for time-series problem in pytorch

Tags: neural-network, time-series, lstm

I am new to ML. I searched a lot about using teacher forcing in LSTM. Without teacher forcing LSTM works well for time series problem but it does not predict well for future sample.

Can somebody help on this please.

Comment: Any answer please.

Comment: Show your research